# select sorted tree and subtrees with materialized path

Tags: mysql

i want select tree from

```
 id  |  parent_id | path     | order
--------------------------------------- 
  1  |     0      | /1/      |   1
  2  |     1      | /1/2/    |   1
  3  |     2      | /1/2/3/  |   1
  4  |     1      | /1/4/    |   2
  5  |     4      | /1/4/5/  |   2
  6  |     4      | /1/4/6/  |   1
```

like this

```
| 1 |   |   |
|   | 2 |   |
|   |   | 3 |  
|   | 4 |   |
|   |   | 6 |
|   |   | 5 |
```

in one query.

Something like

```
select * from tbl ORDER BY COALESCE(length(path),0), order asc
```

but this select sorted groups of each tree level

```
1
-2
-4
--3
--6
--5
```

thanks

Comment: Your example is internally inconsistent. I see no way to get the outcome you want with the data presented. I suggest to make it consistent or explain How exactly the hierarchy works.